# Wi-Fi driver asus TP500l

Tags: networking, drivers

I've usually use this to solve my driver problem:

https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1796

But for a reason unknown for me I'm getting this error message:

```
make -C /lib/modules/4.15.0-29-generic/build M=/home/luiz/Documents/MT7630E_release/rt2x00 modules

make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-29-generic'

arch/x86/Makefile:156: CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support

Makefile:976: "Cannot use CONFIG_STACK_VALIDATION=y, please install libelf-dev, libelf-devel or elfutils-libelf-devel"

  CC [M]  /home/luiz/Documents/MT7630E_release/rt2x00/rt2x00dev.o

/bin/sh: 1: gcc: not found

make[2]: *** [/home/luiz/Documents/MT7630E_release/rt2x00/rt2x00dev.o] Error 127

make[1]: *** [_module_/home/luiz/Documents/MT7630E_release/rt2x00] Error 2

make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-29-generic'

make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Even in the cable isn't working, so I only has internet through other computer

Comment: Start with `sudo apt-get install build-essential`.

Comment: And then add: `sudo apt install libelf-dev` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.